# Logstash 5.1.1 kafka input doesn't pick up existing messages on topic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper

I have the following logstash config with a kafka input

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["mytopic"]
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
    codec => "json"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    action => "update"
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I run the logstash it doesnt pick up old messages on that topic. I was under the impression that the first time logstash runs it will pick up all the messages on a topic that have not been consumed. I checked that this was a new topic and had messages in it which didnt get picked up by logstash when it started running. It does pick up messages which come in on the topic while it's running but not the ones that existed before its commencement. Am I missing something in configuration or is it a quirk of the input itself. The guarantee of messages is of utmost importance for my business needs.

Answer (score 7):

Since you haven't specified a group id for kafka, the imporant considerations are the following:

- Kafka group.id (group_id in logstash kafka configuration) is set to the default for logstash, i.e. "logstash"
- The default Kafka value for enable.auto.commit (enable_auto_commit) in logstash is "true"
- Kafka auto.offset.reset (auto_offset_reset) does not have a default value in logstash so I assume the Kafka default value of latest is used.

So when you run the consumer on some topic and it fails to pick up the messages already in the topic, one of two things is likely happening:

1. There is no existing group with the same group id as the consumer and thus the Kafka default auto.offset.reset value of latest is used and the consumer will ignore the already existing messages.
2. There is an existing group with the same group id ("logstash") and some consumer with this group id has already consumed the existing messages and commited the offsets (this other consumer might have been the one ran by you previously or some other consumers with the same group id). This means other consumers under this group will not re-consume those messages unless somehow explicitly told to do so.

So what you likely want to do is set some Kafka configration, for logstash you should be able to set

> group_id => "some_random_group"
>
> auto_offset_reset => "earliest"

If you run the consumer now, since there is no existing offsets for some_random_group and the reset is earliest, the consumer should consume all the existing messages in a topic and commit the offsets. This means that if after consuming all the messages you run the consumer again, it will not consume the existing messages.

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. We did have multiple consumers running on the machine but for different topics. And no group_id was specified (defaults to logstash). Would that have played a part. In production I only intend to have one consumer but in dev anyone can start a consumer so I am wondering if all those consumers need to have unique group ids.

Comment: If you have specified the same group id for several consumers, i.e. they make up that consumer group, they will all get roughly the same amount of messages. 

So if you had consumers with same group id running while producing, the messages were sent to them. 

In dev I suggest everyone uses different group ids if they don't want their testing to interfere with others' and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

You should set kafka input plugin setting [auto_offset_reset](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.1/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-auto_offset_reset) to "earliest".

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
    topics => ["mytopic"]
  }
}
```

Comment: auto_offset_reset value is used only when Kafka can't find an existing group for the consumer. If this didn't work for you it means that there is an existing group and that some consumer in that group had already consumed the messages and committed the offsets. 

Take a look at my answer.